# How to set Emacs gdb so that it shows recent command on arrow-up?

Tags: emacs, gdb, keyboard-shortcuts, buffer

How can I set Emacs gdb so that it shows the most recent command when I press arrow-up?

In the Emacs gdb it will just go one line up in the buffer.

I know you can always just search backwards in the buffer and select a recent command there, but getting the command directly with arrow-up would be more convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>C-h B</kbd> tell me that <kbd>C-up</kbd> is bound to `comint-previous-input` whose documentation is

```
Cycle backwards through input history, saving input.
```

One could rebind this to <kbd>up</kbd> (and <kbd>down</kbd> for symmetry) with:

```
(eval-after-load "gud"
  '(progn 
     (define-key gud-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input)
     (define-key gud-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'comint-next-input)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you can also cycle through the command history with <kbd>M-p</kbd> (previous command) and <kbd>M-n</kbd> (next command), which is useful when you run Emacs in the terminal where <kbd>C-up</kbd> and <kbd>C-down</kbd> may not be available.